# How to reduce LinkedIn's cookies' length on my website?

Tags: web, cookies, linkedin-api

I am looking for a way to reduce LinkedIn's cookie length on the website of my company.
We currently have **li_gc** and **bcookie** from LinkedIn that expire after 24 months, and I would like them to expire after 12 months instead to align with the ePrivacy Directive.

Can anyone explain how to reduce the expiry period of LinkedIn cookies?
If it is something that our developers can do, which steps should they follow?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have the same question. How to align with the GDPR when some cookies have 24 months life time ?